# TensorFlow on multiple machines with multiple GPUs?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I'm a new in machine learning and Tensorflow. I have a question about distributed training in TensorFlow. I've read about multi GPUs environments and it looks that it is quite possible (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu).

But what about multiple machines with multiple GPUs?  Is it possible to divide machine training tasks between few machines? Is there a specific algorithms/tasks, which require such distribution or multiple GPUs are enough for machine learning? Will there be demand on this?

Thanks

Comment: Of course it is possible. You would have to connect your machines (socket connection) and create different worker classes. Also, create a master class that will assign work to the workers (for example, the first 20% of the training to one worker-machine, the next 20% to the next worker-machine and so on). Your workers should be the same code in each of your machines and they should be parametrized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

You can run same model on multiple machines using data parallelism with [distributed strategies](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distribute_strategy) or [horovod](https://github.com/horovod/horovod) to speed up your training. In that case you are running the same model across multiple machines to emulate a larger batch.

You can also go for a little less conventional way with [GPipe](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/03/introducing-gpipe-open-source-library.html) or [TF-Mesh](https://github.com/tensorflow/mesh) to split a single model across multiple machines to increase number of model layers or even split individual layers across multiple workers.